# How to read from text file with colon in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation

I have usernames and passwords stored in .txt file with double dot and i would like to read from it and store the first half in variable and second half in variable.

> Example :  kmyghz1:aa12345bb12345cckmyghz1

```sh
cat ./examples/secrets.txt | while  IFS=':' | read variable1 variable2 do \
        echo $variable1 \
        echo $variable2 \
done
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Should've edited that "porn" bit out yourself before posting. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar lol , I was using it as a genius example :D

Comment: @DevSolar its actually " cat ./instabut/examples/secrets.txt "

Comment: That "double dot" is, in fact, called "colon". That's why the variant with a dot and a comma (";") is a *semi*colon.

Comment: @DevSolar yeah i always get confused between that and that

Comment: Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find errors in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`IFS=:` by itself is not a command; it's a pre-command assignment for the `read` command. Drop the pipe symbol (`|`) separating them. You are also missing either a semicolon or a newline character preceding the `do` keyword.

```
while IFS=: read variable1 variable2; do
    echo "$variable1"
    echo "$variable2"
done < ./examples/secrets.txt
```

The backslashes are unnecessary, and parameter expansions should always be quoted.

Comment: cat ./instabut/examples/secret.txt | while IFS=: read LINE variable1 variable2; do \
    echo "$variable1"
    echo "$variable2"
done

Comment: I get still ./script.sh: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: cat ./instabut/examples/usernames.txt | while IFS=';' read  userName password;
do
    echo $userName
    echo $password
done < './instabut/examples/secret.txt'

Comment: you're missing `;` before `done` : `cat ./instabut/examples/usernames.txt | while IFS=';' read userName password; do echo $userName echo $password; done

Comment: with that my command line gets stuck on that and doesnt do shit :/

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env bash
cat ./instabut/examples/secret.txt | while IFS=':' read userName password;
do
 echo "$userName"
 echo "$password";
done

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input and this is the right answer that worked for me!

```
while IFS=: read -r userName password
do
 echo "$userName"
 echo "$password"
done < ./instabut/examples/secret.txt
```

Comment: I took the liberty of shuffling things around a bit. You might find the new way a bit easier to read...?!? In any case, it removes the need for semicolon (`;`) and `cat`...

Comment: @DevSolar , Well you saved me 4 bytes. Thank you :)

Comment: It's more about well-structured and readable code, and not doing unnecessary things (like most uses of `cat`...), but you're welcome. ;-)